# Add a Windows Executable File to Maven Repository

Tags: maven

we compile a non Java Windows Executable and want to add this to our Maven Repository. Is it possible? What should we do, to get inserting this .exe-File to Maven Repro?

Thanks for any help

Comment: You can attach any file to an existing maven project for example with the buildhelper-maven-plugin ...?

Comment: Did I understand you right? I create an empty maven project and insert the exe-File with the Plugin into it?

Comment: Yes exactly that's the way...